# Highlighting the same variable

Tags: php, customization, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

Are there any Atom's packages which highlighting the same variable in the code (especially, PHP)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found: [Highlight Selected](https://atom.io/packages/highlight-selected)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I was just going to answer this :)

Comment: Yes, it's very simply function and yet very useful.